# SetUp is not working for NUnit

Tags: .net, unit-testing, nunit

I have following NUnit code. I am using a switch case statement inside [SetUp]

Before the test is run it is expected to insert data into database; but it is not inserting data. What need to be corrected here?

REFERENCE:

1. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/173651/nunit-setup-and-teardown

CODE

```
     [SetUp]
    public void TestSetUp()
    {
        switch (TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.FullName)
        {
            case "GetApplicationsTest":
                GetApplicationsTestSETUPHElper();
                break;

            case "DeleteApplicationTest":
                GetApplicationsTestSETUPHElper();
                break;

        }


    }

    private void GetApplicationsTestSETUPHElper()
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        using (connection)
        {
            string commandText = "INSERT INTO Status_Type VALUES (889,'s2','UT s2')";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    private void DeleteApplicationTestSETUPHElper()
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        using (connection)
        {
            string commandText = "INSERT INTO Status_Type VALUES (890,'s3','UT s3')";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void GetApplicationsTest()
    {

        ApplicationBL application = new ApplicationBL(connectionString);
        ApplicationSearch applicationSearch = new ApplicationSearch();
        applicationSearch.ApplicationID = 1;
        //applicationSearch.ApplicationName = "Test1";
        //applicationSearch.ApplicationURL = "Test1";
        //applicationSearch.StatusCode = 1;
        Collection<Application> applications =  application.GetApplications(applicationSearch);
    }

    [Test]
    public void DeleteApplicationTest()
    {

        ApplicationBL application = new ApplicationBL(connectionString);
        ApplicationSearch applicationSearch = new ApplicationSearch();
        applicationSearch.ApplicationID = 1;
        //applicationSearch.ApplicationName = "Test1";
        //applicationSearch.ApplicationURL = "Test1";
        //applicationSearch.StatusCode = 1;
        Collection<Application> applications = application.GetApplications(applicationSearch);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.FullName
```

is the fully-qualified name of the test, not just the function name as you have it in the code, so the fix ought to be to put the fully-qualified name of the tests in your case statements.

Comment: Thanks. Worked. (Namespace + ClassName + MethodName)